# Give an example of functions $f$ and $g$, both continuous at $x = 0$, for which the composite function $f \circ g$ is discontinuous at $x = 0$.

Tags: calculus

Give an example of functions $f$ and $g$, both continuous at $x = 0$, for which the
composite function $f \circ g$ is discontinuous at $x = 0$.
We know that composition of continuous function is continuous. Then how we can find such an example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The point is that $f$ may not be continuous at $g(0)$, since $g(0)$ may not be $0$. For example, consider $g(x) = x+1$ and $f(x) = 0$ for $x<1$, and $1$ for $x\ge 1$. Then we have $$\lim_{x\to 0+}(f\circ g)(x) = 1,$$ whereas $$\lim_{x\to 0-}(f\circ g)(x) = 0.$$

Comment: very nice answer